# How do I protect the keyboard cursor that will cover the whole value in the text field after using the requestFocus()?

Tags: flutter

I create my custom search picker using the `TextFormField` widget and the `showMenu` function.
This dialog will show between user typing. The problem is when this dialog is displayed, the keyboard cursor will not focus on the text field.
I fix this by using the `focusNode` with the `.requestFocus()` function but this function makes the cursor cover the whole text that not I want. How to protect this? Are there have solutions like `.requestFocus(lastCursor: true)`

At this moment I fix it by using the `TextEditingController` like this

```
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () async {
      //make user can type after display the dialog
      for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (_focusNode.hasFocus) await Future.delayed(Duration.zero);
        if (_focusNode.hasFocus) continue; //make sure that the showMenu UI building is already finished. if this is finished, the _focusNode.hasFocus will be false by this dialog effect.
        final selection = _controller.selection;
        _focusNode.requestFocus();
        Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () => _controller.selection = selection);
        break;
      }
    });
```

But this solution is not complete. We can see the cursor cover the whole text in a short time.

Example video: https://imgur.com/a/OGUOpxE